# tftp booting my raspberry pi, but initramfs file is not requested by the raspberrypi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, dnsmasq, tftp

I am using custom Linux Kernel built through Yocto. I generated **sdimg** and try to boot it using an SDCARD and it boots perfectly fine. Here along with the Kernel I also use **INITRAMFS** files. Using **config.txt** and **cmdline.txt** file in partition 1, I tell the kernel to load my **INITRAMFS** file. This procedure is working fine.

Now, I am trying to net boot my **Raspberrypi**. For this I have another PC which has **DNSMASQ** installed and it acts as DNS server. I have all the required files in my **/tftpboot** directory. When I turn on the client RPI, it gets all the files from the server except my **INITRAMFS** file. I have added the initramfs file name as shown below in the config.txt, but still it is not being requested by my PI. How to make the RPI request for the **INITRAMFS** file? It just boots up the **kernel7.img** and thats it !

```
//appended the following lines to config.txt
ramfsfile=myramfs.cpio.gz     
initramfs myramfs.cpio.gz followkernel
```

Please note that I am not using u-boot.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue. When we do TFTP booting, the first file requested by Raspberry pi(Rpi) is startx.elf, this will be run on the GPU core. Next file that is requested is config.txt. For some reason, if I append the above 2 lines it doesn't work. I read in one of the raspberry pi forums that if the config.txt file is above some size limit, it will be ignored. So I cleared the config.txt file and added just these lines, and voila! Now my initramfs file is requested by the PI and boots successfully :)